# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context but everything looks fine

Tags: php, object, this, fatal-error

I had this class:

```
<?php
class acController {

    protected $_enabledPages = array(
        'front_login.php',
    );

    protected $_enabledDirectories = array (
        'admin'
    );

    public static function isAuthorized() {
        echo '<pre>';
        acController::checkResource($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'], $this->_enabledDirectories);
        acController::checkResource($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'], $this->_enabledDirectories);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    protected static function checkResource($urlAddress, $addressArray) {}
}
```

?>

And I got this error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

But when in this case $this is used within the class and I can't understand where is the problem. In other files I get the information with `acController::isAuthorized();`

Best regards,
George!

Comment: The magic keyword to your problem is `static`: Are you instantiating an acController instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a static function, you cannot $this.

**$this** implies existence of an object(instance of a class). While **static** implies a call to a class.

From the PHP documentation :

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object
>   created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method
>   declared as static.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem because your methods are statics. this represents an instance of the class but if you use it as static, the methods could be used without any instance of the class. So you can't this with statics.